# ¿Un elemento creado en jquery puede crearse un hermano?

Tags: jquery, html5

He creado un elemento en jquery y lo he almacenado en una variable como lo muestro a continuación:

```
x = $("<tr><td> Texto </td></tr>");
```

y si lo imprimo en consola de de esta manera **console.log(x[0])** me imprime lo siguiente

```
<tr><td> Texto </td></tr>
```

Mi pregunta es si es existe una función o una manera para que la variable x pueda crearse un hermano y que cuando imprima en consola me imprima algo similar a lo siguiente

```
<tr><td> Un hermano antes </td></tr> 
<tr><td> Texto </td></tr>
<tr><td> Un hermano despues </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar `clone()` para clonar el elemento, y después `before()` y `after()` para agregarlos antes o despu[es del mismo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let $orig = $("#original");
  let $clon = $orig.clone();
  $clon.text("Soy el clon 1");
  $orig.before($clon);
  $clon = $orig.clone();
  $clon.text("Soy el clon 2");
  $orig.after($clon);
   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="original"><td >Soy el original</td></tr>
<table>
```